# How to insert multiple rows into a table at one time?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I need to send e.g. 5 records in one query into the one table (id_book - is every time different), so I need to by one click on button, create e.g. 10 records. This code shows this Error message:
*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id_book.0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `connect_user_books` where `id_book`.`0` = 6* (MY TEXT: 6 IS ID OF MY LIST INTO WHICH I NEED TO ADD THEASE RECORDS)*)*

**My controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $books = Book::all();

    return view('connectUserBook.create', compact('books'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'id_user_select' => 'required',
        'id_book' => 'required|array',
        'id_book.*' => 'exists:connect_user_books',
    ]);

    $userId = $request->input('id_user_select');

    // Vytvoření
    foreach ($request->input('id_book') as $book) {
        $connect = new ConnectUserBook;
        $connect->id_user_select = $userId;
        $connect->id_book = $book;
        $connect->save();
    }

    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Výběr editován!');
}
```

**My HTML markup:**

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'ConnectUserBookController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}

    <div>
        <label class="form-label">Vybraný výběr *</label>
        <div>
            <select name="id_user_select" class="form-control">

                <?php
                    $select_id = $_GET["id"];
                    $select_id;
                    $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from selected_books Where id = $select_id");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["title"]; ?></option>                     
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    @for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++)
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">Book {{ $i }} *</label>
            <div>
                <select name="id_book[]" class="form-control">

                    @foreach ($books as $book)
                        <option value="{{ $book->id_book }}">{{ $book->nazev }} - {{ $book->pocet_stranek }} stran</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endfor

{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to the StackOverflow, please make the errors into codes so that we can find errors quickly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array and use the insert method with eloquent.

```
$data = array()
foreach ($request->input('id_book') as $book) {
        $data[] = array('id_user_select'=>$userId,'id_book'=>$book);

    }

ConnectUserBook::insert($data);
```

as per your error your need to specify with the column. add a column to compare with which column exists?

```
'id_book.*' => 'exists:connect_user_books,column_name',
```

**Note :-** It doesn't insert the timestamps.

Comment: have you passed column name?

Comment: In your validation here you need to pass your db column.  `'exists:connect_user_books,column_name'`

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
            'id_user_select' => 'required',
            'id_book.' => 'required|array',
            'id_book.*' => 'exists:connect_user_books,id',
        ]);

Comment: do you have id field in connect_user_books table?

Comment: nope, there is only: id_spoj(PK of the table), id_user_select(ID of that selected list) and id_book(id of that selected book)